# Controlar orden de CONCAT_WS

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, concatenación

Estoy haciendo una consulta utilizando CONCAT_WS, pero resulta que a veces cambia el ORDEN de los elementos, me explico:

RESULTADO 1:
valor1 | valor2 | valor3

RESULTADO 2:
valor2 | valor1 | valor3

Existe alguna manera de controlar el orden? les dejo parte del codigo:

```
Select producto, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(COALESCE(codigo,'',numero),numero)SEPARATOR '|') AS codigoBar FROM xxxx INNER JOIN ......
```

Answer (score 1):

`concat_ws()` No cambia el orden, el separador es el primer parámetro.

`group_concat()` Puede cambiar el orden de los *registros agregados* con su cláusula `ORDER BY` antes de `SEPARATOR`:

```
group_concat( columna1, columna2
ORDER BY columna2, columna1 SEPARATOR '|' ).
```